# Send data through curl to influxdb

Tags: shell, curl, timestamp, time-series, influxdb

I want to send data to influx db to database abc and measurement def. In influxdb I have already created a database abc
My shell script is not throughing any error but isn't writing anything in influxdb

```
#!/bin/sh

now=$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S)

if [ ! `pgrep -f -ujava -- 'DMAPPO'` ];

    then

    curl -i -XPOST http://193.64.193.151:8086/write?db=abc --data-binary "def,new="1" time="'"$now"'""; 

    exit 1;

else

    curl -i -XPOST http://193.64.193.151:8086/write?db=abc --data-binary "def,new="0" time="'"$now"'"";

    exit 1;

fi
```

Comment: which version of influx are you using?

Comment: Is your curl call actually executing?
Can you run tcpdump to verify that the data is being posted from the client? If yes, it'll isolate the issue to network or influx. If not, you can focus on troubleshooting the shell script.